# Do items bought from Kadala have a different stat range when bought in a Torment Game?

Tags: diablo-iii

Kadala sells Items for Blood Shards. Since I am fresh 70, I do not have the gear yet to do Torment. But does Torment actually provide different stat ranges for items bought from Kadala?

So basically the idea is to do Bounties and Rifts on Master and then switch to Torment to spend the Blood Shards?

Comment: As far as I've seen, iLevel and rarity determines stat ranges. Difficulty doesn't affect quality of drops meaning anything you can buy/find in normal, can be found in T6.

Comment: @Katustrawfic That is wrong. Normal to Master has the same stat range. Torment has a different one.

Comment: The Torment difficulty description specifically states that some legendaries only drop in torment.

Comment: Related: [A blue post that implies that Torment-only and Horadric-Cache-Only legendaries can't be gained from Kadala](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/12248064907?page=2#23)

Comment: @Assylum no, you're incorrect.  Torment has the same stat range as all other difficulties.  The only difference is that some legendary/set items are exclusive to torment difficulties.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No item, at all, has different stat ranges based on difficulty, regardless of where the item was acquired.  This has been mentioned several times in blue posts.  Some blue posts that corroborate this:

- [Discussion about item drops and quality vs difficulty](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/12091349617?page=5#89)
- [From the same thread; talking about lvl 60, but valid at lvl 70 too](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/12091349617#15)
- [More talking about quality of item vs difficulty](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/12090019460#14)

That said, there **are** exclusive items available only in torment.  These items only drop in torment and are unavailable from Kadala, even if you buy while in torment mode, as mentioned in [this blue post](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/12248064907?page=2#23).